# Last year occurrence of date and month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to find a way to find the last time the day and year combination has happened.

I have a long list of dates and I want to find out what year the date and month has last occurred.

ie. 01/01 has happened in 2018 so I want 2018 as the output.

31/12 has not happened in 2018 yet, the last time is happened was in 2017, so I want 2017 as the output.

Table 1

```
(01/01/2015),
(01/01/2016),
(31/12/2015),
(25/07/2004)
```

Return table 2

```
(01/01/2015, 01/01/2018),
(01/01/2016, 01/01/2018),
(31/12/2015, 31/12/2017),
(25/07/2004, 25/07/2017)
```

OR even just return

```
(01/01/2015, 2018),
(01/01/2016, 2018),
(31/12/2015, 2017),
(25/07/2004, 2017)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @ZMannion Are you looking for day and month combination?

Comment: why has 01/01/2018 reocured?  It is not in Table 1 - I don't understand what you want to check for.

Comment: I have a long list of dates and I want to find out what year the date and month has last occurred.

ie. 01/01 has happened in 2018 so I want 2018 as the output.

31/12 has not happened in 2018 yet, the last time is happened was in 2017, so I want 2017 as the output.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select t2.*,
       (case when month(col) < month(current_date) or
                  (month(col) < month(current_date) and day(col) <= day(current_date))
             then year(current_date)
             else 1 + year(current_date)
        end)
from table2 t2;
```

This is using a reasonable set of date/time functions.  These can vary by database.

Comment: select t2.*,
       (case when month(col) < month(current_date) or
                  (month(col) < month(current_date) and day(col) <= day(current_date))
             then year(current_date)
             else year(current_date) - 1
        end)
from table2 t2;  

This is working for the year now... any idea how to combine them to return the day and month from table 1 and the year returned from the above code?

Comment: @ZMannion . . . This returns what the question says should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

To filter the month and year of a given date to the current date you can use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE month(date) = month(get_some_date()) and year(date) = year(get_somedate())
```

Here you can replace `get_some_date` to your function logic.